# Do I need to copy the templates for third party apps (specifically Django-schedule)?

Tags: python, django

I am a Django newbie trying to use a third party app ([Django scheduler)](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler) to display a calendar for event scheduling. I followed the installation instructions on the github and have successfully installed the app into my environment. I know it is working because it migrated successfully and I was able to create test instances of the Event and Calendar models using the API shell (python manage.py shell). But I am really confused about how to use django-scheduler to augment my current app (i.e. how to make a calendar show up when users are inputting events). Specifically, my question is; do I need to copy all of the templates folders, or should they be automatically included during the installation and I just need to link to them somehow? There is an [example project](https://github.com/llazzaro/django-scheduler-sample) but it does not integrate the scheduler into an existing app so I could not glean the answer from this.